# Use of a class inside another class

Tags: html, css

I have got the following code:

```css
.description p span {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <p>This recipe is from one of my <span class="cor">favorite</span> cakes out there, really <span>delicious</span>...check it out below</p>
</div>
```

but I want the class in the first span tag to remove all text with italic to red

Comment: span:first-child {}

Comment: or span:last-child {}

Answer (score 1):

Use the class which you have given to the span itself.

```css
.description p span {
  font-style: italic;
}

.description .cor {
  font-style: normal;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <p>This recipe is from one of my <span class="cor">favorite</span> cakes out there, really <span>delicious</span>...check it out below</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In addition, if you really wanted to ensure that it was a `span` element being styled, you could use: `.description p span.cor`.

Comment: It only changes the color in the firts span tag, not all span tags

Answer (score 0):

Use Pseudo class selector **:first-child** to select first span.

```
.description p span:first-child{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry did not remove any of the italics in the two span tags

Comment: `.description p span{
  font-style: italic;
}`

`.description p span:first-child{
  font-style: normal;
  color : red;
}`
Try this one

Comment: only the first span tag got red...I need both span tags to change from italic to red

Comment: In such case, you can make changes to your code snippet like `.description p span {
  font-style: normal; color:red;
}`